# Would you help me understand this paragraph?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Stellar black holes form when the center of a very massive star **collapses in upon itself**. This **collapse** also causes a supernova, or an **exploding star**, that blasts part of the star into space. Scientists think supermassive black holes formed at the same time as the galaxy they are in.

What does it mean by *collapses in upon itself* ?

When I read the word *collapse*, I feel like the centre of the star has a gravitational effect and it attracts what is around it to form a black hole. But when I read the word "exploding star", I feel like the star is expanding like a bomb. So, there are two opposite ideas. Which one is true?

Comment: Better asked on physics.stackexchange.com, but the star first collapses in on itself and then explodes outward.

Comment: They're both true, but this is a question for perhaps physics.stackexchange.com. When some stars collapse, the intense pressure can ignite fusion of elements like oxygen, which generates an enormous amount of energy causing an explosion expelling the star's outer layers before the remainder collapses behind its event horizon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for physics.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It first collapses. That collapse causes the explosion. So, both happen, but the collapse happens first, followed by explosion. That is what the sentences seem to imply.